# Tool to Quickly create an unordered list with url links

Tags: html, html-lists

first time here, forgive my ignorance.
I am hoping a tool or process exists where I can plug in a list of titles and urls, and it spits out an html document with an unordered list with hyperlinked titles.
The use case here is that I'm building a website to display a digital version of a print magazine. Each issue requires a contents list in the sidebar, which I am creating with html. It's a fairly tedious process at the moment, and I'd love to find or create a tool that could make it quicker (particularly as I'll be handing it off to someone else on the team at some stage)
All ideas gratefully accepted

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, in this case, you can use arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure I understand your question correctly. But if you want to iterate through a list of something you cannot do it with HTML alone as you would need JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Google Sheets? You can plug in your data, format it how you like and then export it as .html file.

Best,
Chris

Comment: Are you aware of any decent tutorials for this Chris? This sounds promising.

Comment: I've created a sample google sheet, just go to File and from there create a copy.

In the first column, you can fill in Titles and in the second cloumn you can fill in URLs. The hyperlink is automaticly created in the third column.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F2KYgpQ98tgaCq8rIxQwuvCuf0yN4ak9r251eS7zmJs/